How to update this SQL code to group the Case When Groups and provide averages for each distribution group
I need help with the SQL Lite code below. I am hoping to find the averages and counts for each distribution group of numbers of fans. When I run the code I am only seeing the averages for all of the users and the group is appearing as the first group of 0-20 fans.
Thank you!
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN U.Fans >0 AND U.Fans <=20 THEN '0-20 Fans'
        WHEN U.Fans >20 AND U.Fans <=40 THEN '21-40 Fans'
        WHEN U.Fans >40 AND U.Fans <=60 THEN '41-60 Fans'
        WHEN U.Fans >60 AND U.Fans <=80 THEN '61-80 Fans'
    END AS 'Distribution of Fans',
    AVG(U.Review_Count) AS Average_Review_Count,
    AVG(U.Average_Stars) AS Average_of_Average_Stars,
    COUNT(R.Useful = 1),
    COUNT(R.Funny = 1),
    COUNT(R.Cool = 1)
FROM User AS U
INNER JOIN Review AS R ON U.Id = R.User_Id
GROUP BY 'Distribution of Fans'

I tried to group by 'Distribution of Fans' in hopes that I would be able to see averages/counts for each group of fans I created in the Case/When statements.

Please tag the RDMS you are targeting. The sql posted above will not run against every database

You need to subquery your desired grouping field or use it directly in the grouping. You can't group on a derived expression in the same query scope unless the derived expression is also used in the group by. Also, I converted the COUNT(Field=1) to SUM(CASE 1 OR 0)
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN U.Fans >0 AND U.Fans <=20 THEN '0-20 Fans'
        WHEN U.Fans >20 AND U.Fans <=40 THEN '21-40 Fans'
        WHEN U.Fans >40 AND U.Fans <=60 THEN '41-60 Fans'
        WHEN U.Fans >60 AND U.Fans <=80 THEN '61-80 Fans'
        ELSE 'Greater that 80'
    END AS 'Distribution of Fans',
    AVG(U.Review_Count) AS Average_Review_Count,
    AVG(U.Average_Stars) AS Average_of_Average_Stars,
    SUM(CASE WHEN R.Useful = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN R.Funny = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN R.Cool = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM User AS U
INNER JOIN Review AS R ON U.Id = R.User_Id
GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN U.Fans >0 AND U.Fans <=20 THEN '0-20 Fans'
        WHEN U.Fans >20 AND U.Fans <=40 THEN '21-40 Fans'
        WHEN U.Fans >40 AND U.Fans <=60 THEN '41-60 Fans'
        WHEN U.Fans >60 AND U.Fans <=80 THEN '61-80 Fans'
        ELSE 'Greater that 80'
    END

A slightly different approach using a subquery.
;WITH(
    SELECT 
        U.Review_Count,
        U.Average_Stars,
        CASE WHEN R.Useful = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS UsefulFlag,
        CASE WHEN R.Funny = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FunnyFlag, 
        CASE WHEN R.Cool = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CoolFlag,
        R.Funny,
        R.Cool,
        CASE
            WHEN U.Fans >0 AND U.Fans <=20 THEN '0-20 Fans'
            WHEN U.Fans >20 AND U.Fans <=40 THEN '21-40 Fans'
            WHEN U.Fans >40 AND U.Fans <=60 THEN '41-60 Fans'
            WHEN U.Fans >60 AND U.Fans <=80 THEN '61-80 Fans'
            ELSE 'Greater that 80'
        END AS 'Distribution of Fans'
        FROM User AS U
        INNER JOIN Review AS R ON U.Id = R.User_Id
)AS DataWithGrouping

SELECT
    [Distribution of Fans], 
    AVG(U.Review_Count) AS Average_Review_Count,
    AVG(U.Average_Stars) AS Average_of_Average_Stars,
    SUM(UsefulFlag) AS UsefulCount,
    SUM(FunnyFlag) AS FunnyCount,
    SUM(CoolFlag) AS CoolCount
FROM 
    DataWithGrouping
GROUP BY 
    [Distribution of Fans]


Or a CROSS APPLY (VALUES
